# losing time information with dateoffset and bdate_range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am seeing the following behavior when using DateOffset in pandas.

```
In [25]:

import pandas as pnd
d = pnd.Timestamp('2013-01-01 16:00')
dates = pnd.bdate_range(start=d, end=d+pnd.DateOffset(days=5))
for d1 in dates :
    print d1
2013-01-01 00:00:00
2013-01-02 00:00:00
2013-01-03 00:00:00
2013-01-04 00:00:00
```

I am losing the time information. Is there is way to generate a date range that looks like,

```
2013-01-01 16:00:00
2013-01-02 16:00:00
2013-01-03 16:00:00
2013-01-04 16:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `normalize` argument of `bdate_range` (which defaults to True):

```
In [11]: dates = pnd.bdate_range(start=d, end=d+pnd.DateOffset(days=5), normalize=False)

In [12]: for d1 in dates :
             print d1
2013-01-01 16:00:00
2013-01-02 16:00:00
2013-01-03 16:00:00
2013-01-04 16:00:00
```

*Note: some similar functions have a similar argument `base`.*

Comment: hmmm... I did not know about normalize

Comment: It's not in the online docs, you have to check the `help(pd.bdate_range)` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `date_range` easier!:

```
import pandas as pnd
d = '2013-01-01 16:00'
dates = pnd.date_range(d, periods=5, freq='D')
```

to show the output:

```
>>> for i in dates: print i
... 
2013-01-01 16:00:00
2013-01-02 16:00:00
2013-01-03 16:00:00
2013-01-04 16:00:00
2013-01-05 16:00:00
```

As Andy pointed out, you can do this using `bdate_range`, but I prefer this method due to its simplicity and readability

Comment: However the results are different since `bdate_range` only includes business days (which is even clearer if you take a slightly larger range e.g. 10), it just so happens the 2013-01-05 was a Saturday, hence why it's in your but not mine or OPs. :)

Comment: never used `bdate_range` before, guess now I know what it's for haha